# Lookup column automatic selection in list form upon adding new item

Tags: web-part, list, lookup-column, list-form

I have a site page with two related lists, this relation being established via the webpart option **"insert related list"**, and I'm using **ID column** in my child list as the lookup column.

The child list is properly being filtered when I select some of the items in the parent list, but when adding new items, I need to **manually associate the correct parent id** I want the child item to be linked with, **even if a parent list item is previously selected** in its respective webpart.

I searched around, but no clues yet. Not sure whether I was clear enough, but any help will be appreciated.